# How can Shan Elariel burn brass in her glove?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

Of the Mistborn Series, I am still listening to the first audio book. But I think this question won't be answered by me reading further:

Kelsier is told (I forget whom by) that she has a slither of Brass she uses to sooth people, hidden in a glove or sleeve. How is this possible (burning on only skin contact)? Allomantic powers come from ingesting flakes, and 'burning' them (in the stomach).

What is she doing? Has she previously swallowed the standard flakes, and these are rumours?

Comment: Hoid is the informant that mentions this tidbit to Kelsier: "She always carries a thin envelope of shaved brass in her right glove."

Comment: Also, brass isn't used to soothe. It's used to riot. I was extremely confused when I read this. Simply a typo. The book should have said zinc.

Comment: @BFay, have  you read our [tour]? You should know this isn't mike a forum with lots of discussion. This is  question and answer site. Also, regardless: http://mistborn.wikia.com/wiki/Brass you have  your metals mixed up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a question of storage :-) Most Mistborn store their phials of metals on belt loops or in pouches; she stores her up her sleeve, that's all.

Comment: Doesn't she need to ingest it to use the powers?

Comment: @Pureferret Yes; presumably she yawns (or takes a drink, or anything that brings her hand to her mouth), deposits the brass, and swallows it. It's much more subtle than carrying around a phial and drinking from it.